# execute a jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've got a plugin that binds to a selector eg. a button. and when i click on the button then the function executes (showing a windows where i can choose a picture to upload).

the code looks like this:

```
$('#image_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader':         '../../frontend/jquery/plugins/uploadify/swf/uploadify.swf',
    'script':           'controllers/ajaxcalls/image.php',
});
```

so it binds to a button with id="image_upload". but this will give the button a different look and i dont want that. i want a regular button look.

so i thought i could use a regular  and then when i click on that one, it executes uploadify plugin.

is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/). As far is I understand, settings the option

```
wmode: 'transparent'
```

should **hide the flash-thingy** and **make your original button visible**.

You could also have a look at the `buttonText  buttonImg  hideButton  rollover  width  height  cancelImg` options that should allow you to style the button according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Uploadify uses a flash button to take advantage of Flash's file uploading abilities. You can't  bind it to a normal button as far as I know.

You can style the button though, [this thread has some tips](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=559).

Comment: but there has to be a way to trigger a plugin. eg. simulate a click so that the plugin will be triggered.

Comment: You can manually call $('#image_upload').uploadifyUpload() from another button's click event, but the flash button is still needed to select which files to upload.

Comment: that is exactly what i need to do, to call the $('#image_upload').uploadify() from a regular <button>. how do i do that? would be a great help if you could help me with the caller code.

Comment: No, it is not. This would still make the upload button a flash button. I think you don't understand how this plugin works. No matter from where you call it, it will generate a flash button, and only this specific flash button will have the upload functionality.